# Pipenv cannot create bin folder Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: pipenv

I'm trying to setup Pipenv on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I used:

```
sudo apt install pipenv
```

but I get an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/foo/.local/share/virtualenvs/hello-JDpq8NmY/bin/python'
```

I tried to update pip with:

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10
```

Still no use.

I tried the solution suggested [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5075#issuecomment-1107460002) and nothing changed.

The environment is there but the bin folder is missing.

Comment: That's because your terminal is acting like its attached to a virtual env but can't find the interpreter.  Try running `deactivate` inside the terminal and then try again.  Or open a new terminal session.  If none of those work you need to look at your enviornment variables

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Remove pipenv from apt package manager and install pipenv with

```
pip install pipenv
```

After this you must set your PATH Variable to the pip dictionary.

Comment: i tried what you said which is i think similar to [here](https://gist.github.com/planetceres/8adb62494717c71e93c96d8adad26f5c) I remember it installing ubuntu 18.04 the problem here is probably from ubuntu 22.04 someone noted this on the question and i additionally mentioned it in the title. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem is related to pipenv not finding the python executable.

If this is your case is it possible to specify the path

```
pipenv install --python=/usr/bin/python3.10
```

Replace the path with desired python version

[source](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3488)